# Something like is_term for wordpress conditional tags

Tags: wordpress, api

All thing I need is a Function that check for is a term available for current taxonomy in a page.for example when I want to check is a page available in a post_type I use:

```
<?php if('my_taxonomy' == get_post_type() // DoSomeThing) ?>
```

now I want to use something like this:

```
<?php if(is_term_in_current_taxonomy('my_term')) ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally  founds what i want by myself , the conditional tags is :

```
in_array("BMW" , get_terms( 'cars', array('fields'    => 'names'))) AND 'products' == get_post_type()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like this, place the function below in function.php:

```
function is_term_in_current_taxonomy($term){
    if($term == get_post_type())
        return true;
    elseif(//some condition)
        return true/false;
    :
}
```

Comment: you see man , the `get_post_type()` just return the post type , i just want to check if the terms of current viewing page is under the current taxonomy for example : 
we have a taxonomy that named 'cars' and it have a 3 term , `BMW` , `benz` , `fiat` , in some page we want to check :
1- if the page have 'cars' taxonomy ? 
2- if the current page that have `cars` , contain for example `BMW`?
in totally i want to check the terms in a page.